# Snapshot error type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data and display using `FutureBuilder` . After fetch call it displaying `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Here my json model:

```
class Featured {
  final int id;
  final String shop_type;
  final String name;
  final String name_bn;
  final String price;
  final String price_bn;
  final bool old_price;
  final String old_price_val;
  final String old_price_val_bn;
  final String image;

  Featured(
      {this.id,
      this.shop_type,
      this.name,
      this.name_bn,
      this.price,
      this.price_bn,
      this.old_price,
      this.old_price_val,
      this.old_price_val_bn,
      this.image});

  factory Featured.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Featured(
        id: json['id'],
        shop_type: json['shop_type'],
        name: json['name'],
        name_bn: json['name_bn'],
        price: json['price'],
        price_bn: json['price_bn'],
        old_price: json['old_price'],
        old_price_val: json['old_price_val'],
        old_price_val_bn: json['old_price_val_bn'],
        image: json['image'][0]['image_mobile_feature_list']);
  }
}
```

and main widget

```
class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsState createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {

  Future<List<Featured>> getProducts() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(kIndexFeaturedUrl));
    List<Featured> list = List();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      var rest = data["results"] as List;
      list = rest.map<Featured>((json) => Featured.fromJson(json)).toList();
      return list;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Network connection failed');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getProducts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(
            'test',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          );

        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
        }

        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

update 0:  data sample

```
{id: 1, name: example, name_bn: example, price: 88, price_bn: 80, old_price: false, old_price_val: null, old_price_val_bn: null, image: [{image_mobile_feature_list: https://xyz/media/CACHE/images/shop/product/IMG_1057_-_Copy_3FW1ZM7/1781f5617cc7efe708439802736d8ea7.webp, image_mobile_product_details: https://xyz/media/CACHE/images/shop/product/IMG_1057_-_Copy_3FW1ZM7/fe2589e7b7df5e542aaf37cb52c44523.webp}]}
```

update 1:

`I/flutter ( 1961): int  // id
I/flutter ( 1961): int   // price
I/flutter ( 1961): String  // price_bn
I/flutter ( 1961): Null  // old_price_val`

Comment: One of the `String` properties that you are receiving from your server is actually an `int`. We cannot guess, though. Show us a sample of the data you are receiving. You can do that by placing `print(json);` inside the `Featured.fromJson` `factory`.

Comment: @HugoPassos updated my question. I also found that my price field is int , so I change String to int, still facing same problem.

Comment: Seems like we cannot differentiate an `int` from a `String` with `print`. If you run `print('80')` you'll see the same as `print(80)`. The best option you got in printing `runtimeType`, so create a print for `id`, `price` and `price_bn`. E.g.: `print(json['id'].runtimeType);`.

Comment: updated my question with output

Comment: May I ask you why `price` and `price_bn` have different types? What `bn` stands to?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. `price_bn` means  price in Bengali (ex: "৮৮")  thats why it is string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `toString()` to your `price` property.

```dart
price: json['price'].toString(),
```

I bet `old_price_val` is also an `int` when it's not null. I would call `toString()` for it as well.